# Prevent keyword syntax highlighting within moredelim

Tags: listings, syntax-highlighting

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    keepspaces=true,
    upquote=true,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\color{gray},
    language=c,
    moredelim=*[is][\itshape]{((:}{:))},
    showstringspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{olive},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    identifierstyle=\color{violet},
    stringstyle=\color{purple},
    directivestyle=\color{teal},
}
\begin{document}
Here is the skeleton of the proposed solution:

\begin{lstlisting}
int f(int x)
{
    if (x <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ((x | CONNECT_FLAG) != 0) {
        ((:statements:))
    } else if ((x | DROP_FlAG) != 0) {
        ((:statements:))
    } ((:if else if ladder continues:))

    return result;

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Problem:

In line 11 of the source code output, `if` and `else` are syntax highlighted as keywords. I was expecting them to be highlighted with the `moredelim` style.

How can I prevent them from being syntax highlighted as keywords and be highlighted with the `moredelim` style instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line

```
moredelim=*[is][\itshape]{((:}{:))},
```

to

```
moredelim=[is][\itshape]{((:}{:))},
```

A single star denotes nested syntax highlighting, where the style of detected keywords etc. will be applied instead of the delimiter style. Remove the star to prevent `listings` from looking for other syntax elements within the delimiter. (Additionally, two stars will apply both styles cummulatively.)

Result:

[image]